# It's possible to create a C# package that doesn't need anything else to works in any PC with?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, publishing

I have an application in C# that I made in Visual Studio 2012 and I need people to test it. The only way I have found to send my application is to publish it and send the `setup.exe` with the other files, but, if someone wants to use it, they need to install .NET framework (as far as I know) and it asks to install `VisualBasicPowerPacksSetup` (I'm not sure what it is, but it asked when I tried to install in other PC) first. Is there a way to make a package of files (like needed dll or something) that the receiver can just download all the files in one folder and execute or install it without needing to install other separated things?
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not possible, due to the fact that various versions of windows (All Server versions, and XP) don't have the .NET Framework installed by default. Furthermore Microsoft is quite clear that windows is not a distribution platform for the .NET Framework, MFC, ATL, or MSVC (all versions) and that you are required to make sure that the redistributes are distributed with your application, or installed from their servers.

Comment: Does Windows 7 and 8 have .NET Framework installed by default? And what do you know about the `VisualBasicPowerPacksSetup` that was required when I tryed to install my application in other computer?

Comment: Windows 7 ships with .NET 3.5 installed by default, Windows 8 ships with .NET 4.5. However again these can be disabled or uninstalled by the user do not presume that they are there. The VisualBasicPowerPacksSetup means you are using a control from that toolkit, your application will not run without it. That is not shipped by default on any windows system.

Comment: Do you know where I can find a list of the controls from that toolkit so I can know what I'm using to try remove it? Just deleting it will solve the need of this package or I need to remove something else manually?I'm now at C# and doesn't know much, yet.

Comment: At least in visual studio 2010, the toolbox control is partitioned by where the various controls come from. Or you can go looking in the designer.cs for your various forms, one of them will have a reference to that namespace (I believe it's `Microsoft.VisualBasicPowerPack`). From there you should be able to track down the control name and remove it via the designer.

Comment: I have always used the "All Windows Forms" tab, never noticed the other tabs. Thanks. So, I found what controls that are from that package, but I just tested them and I didn't leave any of them in any of may forms. Why it asks for the package when I tried to install it in other computer. Someone knows how can I remove it completely from my application so it won't be need by other people. Thanks.

Comment: Make sure you've removed the reference to it in the project, and then check the dependencies listed in the publish wizard.

Comment: I have found the reference and removed it, thanks, but where can I se the dependencies listed in the publish wizard?

Comment: Try the directions on [MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tx0bw8y.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tx0bw8y.aspx)

Comment: Find it, thanks for all your help. I didn't think anyone would help me so much. I just need to get home to test this properly, but I shouldn't have any more problems. Thank you very much.